# Why using a mobile app during a visit on Museum or historical Place

Tags: mobile, questionnaire, concept, user-habit

I'm a student doing a project concept work about designing an application to use on a historical place. I was researching what type of questions I would ask to potential users about using an application during a visit.

I want to know what kind of experience do you have on using applications during visits in general and I want to know if you like it or not and why.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SE UX is not the place to ask for app content. We can help with methods on how to find out (from your users) what the content should be.

Comment: Ok, i undestand that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I usually want to see a gallery to get inspired first, with some kind of interactivity on that gallery of images, videos, and to have access to a map, so location it’s important. If I am in a wheelchair or have someone with me that needs help, accessibility to wheelchairs, children facilities and so on can make a huge difference. If the historical place is far away from my residence I expect suggestions of hotels, car parks, supermarkets. Price is also important, so clear information on those it’s advisable even if it is free. Contacts, online customer service or phone are also important. I am not sure if this has helped. Sometimes it’s better to create a rough MVP and test it so see if people have any need that you might not have foreseen, but I think surveys, like the one you are doing it’s a great starting point.

Comment: The historical place that I’m working with are places that have roman mosaics and ruins from ancient roman population, basically the place its similar what u talk about in the third paragraph from your answer.

What I’m trying to reach with this question is to understand how people think about a mobile app that can bring more than just support the visit but to be something that increase the experience. In this first get in touch with people, I want to start with this simple questions and then start concept the idea for this app.

Thank you for the reply, i appreciate a lot!

Comment: Hi. I see... have you thought creating something interactive with certain locations, using VR or even create a story based on a life of one of its inhabitants that e plains the place for instance? Happy to help.